# CSS newbie: horizontally aligned divs keep breaking my layout

Tags: css, responsive-design, html

I'm making my first site and I'm having an issue with some buttons I've created. They are three divs within another div, and horizontally aligned. Here's the html:

```
<div class="buttons">
<div id="next-event"></div>
<div id="blog"></div>
<div id="about"></div>
</div>
```

Here's the CSS:

```
.buttons {
height: 200px;
}

#next-event, #about, #blog {
width: 155px;
padding-bottom: 30px;
}


#blog {
margin-right: 125px;
float: right;
height: 155px;
background: url(assets/blog.png) no-repeat;
}

#blog:hover {
background-position: -155px 0px;
}

#next-event {
margin-left: 125px;
float: left;
height: 155px;
background: url(assets/next-event.png) no-repeat;
}

#next-event:hover {
background-position: -155px 0px;
}

#about {
display: inline-block;
width: 95px;
height: 155px;
background: url(assets/about.png) no-repeat;
}

#about:hover {
background-position: -155px 0px;
}
```

I'm having problems when I resize the window in and out, as you can see at the site: http://madeitseries.com/

For scrolling in, how to I set it so the containing div for the yellow buttons gets longer only when the window is below a certain width?

And for scrolling out, how do I set it so the yellow buttons distribution only spreads to a certain point?

Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So to position the buttons, you could use a grid: http://youtu.be/0IrWRuEyXYA

Or you could use a [media query](http://css-tricks.com/css-media-queries/) to change the styles once the screen gets to a certain size so they don't overlap each other

**Edit: Here's a link to the fiddle with the media query and it working properly as I imagine you want it to. I've removed the floats and margins, set the .buttons div to be the width of the buttons, set .buttons height to auto, and centred them using margin: 0 auto; http://jsfiddle.net/W6B2L/**

```
@media screen and (max-width: 770px) {
#about {
    display: block;
}
.buttons {
    height: auto;
    width: 185px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
#blog {
    margin-right: 0px;
    float: none;
}
#next-event {
    margin-left: 0px;
    float: none;
}
```

}

Comment: Thanks Shane – did you save that link? Your changes didn't appear when I clicked it. The media query seems to be the best route to go down, I didn't really know how to do that.

Comment: @aoifac Sorry, had the wrong link. Try the new one :) The media query is at the end of the CSS. If you add that to your CSS it'll work.

Media queries are very powerful, and you'll need to grasp them if you want your site to be responsive. Luckily it's very straightforward.

Comment: @aoifac Here's some resources that should help:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries
| 
http://www.htmlgoodies.com/beyond/css/introduction-to-css-media-queries.html
| 
http://css-tricks.com/css-media-queries/

Comment: You could also sign up for a free trial to Lynda.com and check out the following: http://www.lynda.com/Developer-Mobile-Web-tutorials/Applied-Responsive-Design/114899-2.html | http://www.lynda.com/Web-Responsive-Design-tutorials/Responsive-Design-Fundamentals/104969-2.html | http://www.lynda.com/Web-Interactive-CSS-training/CSS-Page-Layouts/86003-2.html

Comment: Wow thank you so much for your help, that's awesome! I'll be sure to check those links out.

Answer (score 0):

set the `height` of the buttons div to `auto`

if you want the buttons to resize according to the width of the screen, give them each a width of 33.33%.

Comment: Thanks Anubhav, but I don't want the buttons to resize, I want the space between each button to get wider and thinner, but only up to a point. So when the screen gets narrow they stack on top of one another, and when the screen gets wider they go beside each other, but they don't continue to spread all the way across the screen as the window gets even wider. Do you know if there's a way to do this?

Comment: try creating a fiddle as it will be hard to explain this way

Answer (score 0):

Why can't you use css media query like below,

```
@media (max-width: 740px)
    {
        .buttons div
        {
            height: 100px !important;
            width: 100px !important;
            background-size: 200% !important;
            padding: 0 !important;
        }
    }
```

Just copy this code into your css file.. when your webpage shrinks(resize) below 740px, then your images automatically resized as per the below code.. Like that you can customize your own codes for your desired screen resolution...

**Note:** Just use this code in your web page.. It might works.. And you need to customize for the hover state only..